# What do the various Tk cursors mean?

Tags: user-interface, cursor, definition, cursors, tk-toolkit

My Google-fu is failing me. Please, consider the following:
http://tcl.activestate.com:8000/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/cursors.htm

Some of the cursors I understand easily enough, "watch" tells the user to wait, "left_ptr" indicates that I can select something under the cursor, "hand2" seems to be the "you're dragging something" cursor.

What are the conventions for the others? Is there a reference?

Specifically, I'm looking for a cursor that says "you can drag from here" when it hovers over a DragDrop source. I've been using "hand1", but is that the convention?

Answer (score 1):

See http://wiki.tcl.tk/13165, a Tk cursor demo written by Richard Suchenwirth